# Stuck with responsiveness in bootstrap 4.6

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

when i resize the browser my sections are mixing each other
one section has  two rows and 12 images
then
new section starts
and it has only one header if i resize my chrome browser those things are mixing
but in inspect tools it is not mixing working very well

why is that

here is my code

```css
.second-page {
    height: 100vh;
}

.second-page img {
    width: 230px;
    height: 137px;
    padding: 5px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: .5s;
}

.second-page img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: .3s;
}


/* second-page ends  */


/* third-page starts  */

.third-page {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="second-page">
            <h1 class="text-center my-5">Intended Projects</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 my-5 text-center">
                    <a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/3.png"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/4.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/5.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 my-5 text-center">
                    <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/3.png"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/4.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/5.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="images/6.jpg"><img src="https://cdnuploads.aa.com.tr/uploads/Contents/2020/05/30/thumbs_b_c_a4a6996640e91d4ff86a71f5d9d9f84b.jpg?v=225920" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </section>
    
        <!-- second-page ends -->
    
        <!-- third-page starts -->
        <section class="third-page ">
            <h1 class="text-center">Our Developers Team</h1>
        </section>
```

Comment: Your questions is quite confusing, could you try and rephrase what the issue is

Comment: can you arrange your sentence so that its easier for us to read?

Comment: sorry it might be the reason that my english is bad         the problem is when i resize my browser to check it's responsiveness    my header in section 3 is going behind the images   but if i inspect this page and check responsiveness it is working well and the header is going to bottom after images       to see my problem you can copy and paste it to code editors and open this with chrome then check the difference with resizing browser and inspecting

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not clear, still i've made this section responsive!
Add link of image in href, replacing #.
The third section is merged in second! it has to be inside a  .

```
<section class="second-page">
        <h1 class="text-center my-5">Intended Projects</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 my-5 text-center">
                <a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/3.png"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/4.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/5.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 my-5 text-center">
                <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/3.png"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/4.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/5.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
                <a href="images/6.jpg"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1 class="text-center">Our Developers Team</h1>
        </div>

    </section>
```